# Use onchange callback option for selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I am trying to use the `onChange` callback for `selectizeInput` within Shiny.

The following code works - when the option on the drown-down menu is changed, the text output appears. However, it is not easily generalised. I must create the selectize as text with the callback within it and then pass it to the UI within `HTML()`.

```r
library(shiny)

js_select = '<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" id="yes-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
  <div>
    <select id="yes" class="form-control" onchange=get_id(this.id)> ### manual callback
<option value="a" selected>a</option>
<option value="b">b</option></select>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="yes">{"plugins":["selectize-plugin-a11y"]}</script>
  </div>
</div>'

js_assign = 'function get_id(clicked_id) {
     Shiny.setInputValue("current_id", clicked_id, {priority: "event"});
};
'

ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js_assign))),
  HTML(js_select),
  strong("has selectizeInput been changed yet:"),
  textOutput("last_clicked"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$last_clicked = renderText({ input$current_id })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Based on several other questions & answers here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802851/7742981), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61216420/7742981), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179022/7742981)) and the selectize.js documentation ([here](https://selectize.dev/docs/usage#event-callbacks)) it looks like I should be able to set `onChange` as an option.

The below code takes this approach. It is much more elegant and easier to generalise. However, when I test it, I can never get the `onchange` event to trigger. What am I doing wrong?

```r
library(shiny)

js_assign = 'function get_id(clicked_id) {
     Shiny.setInputValue("current_id", clicked_id, {priority: "event"});
};
'

ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js_assign))),
  selectizeInput(
    "yes",
    "Yes",
    choices = c("a", "b"),
    options = list(onchange = I("get_id(this.id)")) ### callback as option
  ),
  strong("has selectizeInput been changed yet:"),
  textOutput("last_clicked"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$last_clicked = renderText({ input$current_id })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have varied capitalization (`onChange` vs. `onchange`) and whether `I(.)` is used or not. Neither makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onChange` option of **selectize** must be a function of one argument: the value of the option. For example you can try

```
onChange = I("function(value) {
  alert(value);
}")
```

So the way you use is conceptually wrong (not a function) and I don't know which id you want to get? If this is the id of the select input, you can get it in `this.$input.attr('id')` (to use in the body of the function).